# Wavefront Alert for AWS RDS Freeable Memory

Tags: memory, amazon-rds, alerts, wavefront

I have multiple RDS instances that is monitored in Wavefront with AWS RDS integration dashboard.

Question: What WQL query should I use to create an Alert that will trigger when the **aws.rds.freeablememory** value is less that 5% of total RAM for corresponding RDS instance?

NOTE: The instance type are of different RAM size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the feedback I received from Wavefront support team, there is no parameter available currently. so this type of alert cannot be created.